# Hardest slitherlink you know

Tags: difficulty-rating, slitherlink

What is the hardest slitherlink board you have seen/solved/tried to solve? I've tried googling for some hard ones but came up with simple ones or sites describing what slitherlink even is... So in other words - please provide examples of some hard/hardest boards you know (standard slitherlink rules but it can consist of any shapes - doesn't have to be squares).

Comment: Are slitherlinks with *slightly* modified rules allowed?

Comment: Feel free to post them but partially I asked my question to find out if there even are any really hard boards or if this puzzle is limited in that regard.

Comment: Are you familiar with gmpuzzles.com/blog? They have many slitherlink puzzles, and in general their puzzles posted towards the end of the week are more difficult. This link will show you all of theirs: https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/category/loop/slitherlink/ and here are some of the hardest ones: https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/tag/slitherlink-2+classic+fridaysaturday/ (not sure how consistently they apply the day of week tags)

Comment: Nikoli also has some devious puzzles at the deep end. There is also a site that gives a weekly gigantic 20x20 slitherlink, but I don't remember the name.

Comment: Thx Eric. Although sadly they're not very difficult. Which makes me wonder again if it's even possible to create a slitherlink board that would be a real challenge.

Comment: What about a 3-D board? That might add to the challenge?

Comment: I wanted challenge by increasing the difficulty level, not changing rules/variants. But sure, if you have some 3D ones, please show them to me, I've never seen 3D slitherlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website has the hardest slitherlinks that I know of: **http://kwontomloop.com/puzzle.php**

---

Also, as mentioned in the comments by Eric, https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/category/loop/slitherlink/
has really good slitherlinks

Comment: Kwon-Tom Loop kicked my ass. I can't even solve a medium one. :P Finally some really hard ones, **thank you**!

Comment: And the best part is, it keeps on changing :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Slitherlink/index.htm got some puzzles up to 45x31. You can sort them by size (Größe) or difficulty (Schwierigkeitsgrad).

http://www.nikoli.com/en/puzzles/slitherlink/ got some hard ones, but only a few free samples.

https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/loopy.html can generate puzzles of any size, limited only by your computer's power (and your patience). It also has different types of grids, which can be more difficult.

There is also the [In-Out](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Varianten/018.a.htm) and [Colorlink](http://www.janko.at/Raetsel/Varianten/019.a.htm) variant

Comment: There's a similar version to In-Out in our local newspaper puzzle page with rabbits outside and cabbages inside or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three sites where you can find very difficult puzzles:

https://www.themissingdocs.net/bridge/LoopDeLoopBridge.html

https://www.kakuro-online.com/slitherlink/

kwontomloop.com

If you want to start with the most difficult, try an "Unlimited" at the first site.